# Centering a png on a gradient background

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center a png on top of my gradient background but I can't get it to work.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* Standard syntax */
}
#rocket1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/octicons/3.1.0/octicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="rocket1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img912/5645/0w5agB.png">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know that absolute position doesn't work with margin, however, that's the only way I can get the png ON the background instead of leaving a white space. How can I do it?

**This is what I have now**

[image]

**This is how I want it to be**

[image]

Comment: position:absolute; to add your css

Comment: Take a look at W3C's examples: [CSS centering things](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).

Comment: If any of the answer below works for you. You should accept it as answer by clicking on right symbol below vote of particular user.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `position: absolute` and `transform: translate()`

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#02747A, #48266C); /* Standard syntax */
}

#rocket1 {
  height: 70%;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<img id="rocket1" src="http://imageshack.com/a/img912/5645/0w5agB.png">
```

Comment: Is there alternative to vertically and horizontally center element and its not using table or flexbox and its responsive?

Comment: @NenadVracar There wasn't any need for vertical centering. She was trying to figure out how to center align a relative element with auto margins. Most common practice. The reason it wasn't working didn't need changing the position or extra lines of code. It just needed to change an inline element to a block element.

Comment: Looking at title of question and picture i think she was trying to center it, but lets see what OP says.

Answer (score 2):

You should add

```
display: block;
```

to your #rocket1

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y2fyytw/3/)